# Difference between Fabrica8, Vert.x , Karaf, Felix , Equinox, Spring DM and Fuse and Docker

Tags: java, spring, maven, containers, microservices

I am planning to convert from my Monolithic Server Architecture to a Microservice Architecture. I have been doing some research based on my Pre-requisits.

> **pre-requisits:**
>
> 1) Spring-Boot Application
>
> 2) Build Tool : Maven
>
> 3) Create OSGI bundles from my packages

Based on my understanding, I want my inheritance to be maintained. I do not want a lot of disruption in my project. Here are two more cents from my end.

**1) Containers are a good way to develop and deploy microservices, and the tools and platforms for running containers are a good way to manage microservice-based applications.**

So I was keen on finding containers provided for Spring-Boot Application. There has been a lot of turbulence in the Spring Environment. After the Spring DM was shut, There was an inflow of multiple container providers.

**2) I am not looking for Virtualization and hence do not require Docker.**

---

**MAIN QUESTION**

> **Which is the best container for OSGI Bundles in Spring?**

---

**ADDITIONAL QUESTIONS**

> 1) Please let me know the nuances between [Fabrica8](http://fabric8.io/gitbook/springBootContainer.html) and [Apache
>   Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/download.html) which is apparently based on [Felix](http://felix.apache.org/) or Equinox. There's
>   new versions of Karaf coming up and competing with Fabrica8.l Which
>   one is the best?
>
> 2) Can Docker or [Vert.x.](http://vertx.io/) be useful with such requirements.
>
> 3) Optional. Please give more insights on the above mentioned
>   frameworks if you will.

Comment: so you are basically asking to do your research for you?

Comment: Just for future, if you ask people not to downvote, they'll probably downvote. That being said, I don't really see a question here, unless you're asking us to compare different products, libraries, or plugins which is off topic for the site.

Comment: Can you please suggest me where should I be posting the question. This is a very genuine and common misconception around the world. I'd like to get away with the confusion. Generally people do have a ready recknoner or who are willing to be comprehensive about their answers can shed some light. Thanks for your review though.

Comment: Each stackexchange site has a help center. For example here's [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I want to say one people generally recommend for comparing is SuperUser. I have personally not used that SE site, so you will want to check in their help center to confirm. If it is ever not clear after checking the help center, I would recommend posting in the meta site for that SE. There, people can tell you if it's on or off topic.

Comment: You also might be able to go to Meta StackExchange to see where a question can be asked. They may have tags that reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OSGI > Java Component Deployment**

Converting Java Modules into Components and Deploying them independently.

> units of resources called bundles
>
> Bundles can export services or run processes
>
> bundle can be expected to have its requirements managed by the container
>
> any valid OSGi bundle can theoretically be installed in any valid OSGi container
>
> is lightweight in the sense that it offers very few services
>
> has little runtime overhead

```
OSGi Container > Implementations > 

OSGi Release 4 Core Framework
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   |Core Open Source Implementations
|   |               |
|   |               |
|   |               |
|   |               |Apache Felix
|   |               |Eclipse Equinox (Eclipse IDE is built on this.)
|   |               |Knopflerfish
|   |
|   |
|   |OSGi runtime environment (wraps an OSGi Core and provide developers with a simple interface to manage their OSGi applications) 
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |Apache Karaf (Felix Core)
|               |Eclipse Virgo (Equinox Core)
|
|
|
|Dependency Injection Framework for OSGI
            |
            |
            |
            |Blueprint (Blueprint support the dynamic nature of OSGi services by describing how the components get instantiated and wired together)
```

**Usage Wise (Highest to Lowest) :**

1. OSGi R4 Core Bundle521 > Apache Felix
   org.apache.felix » org.osgi.core under OSGI Containers
   OSGi Service Platform Release 4 Core Interfaces and Classes.
2. Apache Karaf :> Assemblies :> Default Distribution107 
   org.apache.karaf » apache-karaf under OSGI Containers
   Apache Karaf :> Assemblies :> Default Distribution
3. Apache Aries Blueprint Bundle84 
   org.apache.aries.blueprint » org.apache.aries.blueprint under OSGI Containers
   This bundle contains the standalone implementation along with the API. It's composed of the blueprint-api, blueprint-core and blueprint-cm modules.
4. Osgi4 > Apache Equinox
   org.eclipse.equinox » osgi under OSGI Containers

**OSGI > Uses**

> Modular architecture reduces complexity
>
> allows for better changeability
>
> parallel development
>
> reuse and flexibility
>
> reducing time and expenses for development and maintenance

**OSGI Container > Functions**

> install new bundles
>
> start them
>
> stop them
>
> uninstall them
>
> check their dependencies
>
> check registered services
>
> number of other things
>
> executes the container's boot process
>
> each container has a different startup environment
>
> each container has slightly different capabilities

**OSGI Container > Bundles**

> container is running
>
> each bundle consists of one or more Java packages
>
> each bundle has a MANIGEST file
>
> the Packages and Manifest file are bundled into a JAR
>
> First bundle has an id of "0"
>
> ID is used to control the bundle's lifecycle.
>
> bundle provides a lifecycle and exported service
>
> > OSGi bundle requires an "activator"
> >
> > "Activator" manages the lifecycle of the bundle
> >
> > at least one of bundle contains an Activator
> >
> > a feature is a set of bundles that provide a particular facility.

**OSGI Container > Life Cycles**

> starting
>
> stopping
>
> updating
>
> or removing bundles and downloading of management policies
>
> remotely and via an API

**OSGI Container > Services**

> services can be provided by one bundle to another bundle dynamically
>
> service registry allows bundles to detect the addition of new services, or the removal of services, and adapt accordingly.

**Apache Karaf**

> Karaf bundles are platform-specific because Karaf uses native-code libraries
>
> Starts simply by unpacking the distribution bundle into any convenient directory

**Apache Karaf > Commands**

osgi:list

osgi:install file:/path/to/my/bundle.jar

osgi:start [id]

osgi:stop [id]

osgi:uninstall [id]

find-class [class_name]